# Why linked in share button is not working

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am using a LinkedIn share button, but it is not getting content/image from my web page, it is just getting website url and that's all. I am using the following code, please see and let me know what is problem with it.

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/Share"
    data-url="http://www.websiteurl/blog/2014/03/obamacare-health-plans-may-prove-costly-cancer-patients/"
     data-counter="right">
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the image goes, it might not be the right minimum size (80 x 150 px, according to the link below). You might also want to try explicitly setting which image to use using metadata tags described in the link below, for example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.websiteurl/images/blah.png" />
```

More:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares

Answer (score 0):

For LinkedIn share button, content/image.

Try the link u will get some idea.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api